# Latest fsriver plugin not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have issue with latest `fsriver` plugin.
I executed following command to index document

```
PUT _river/mynewriver2/_meta
{
    "type": "fs",
    "fs": {
        "url": "d://tmp",
        "update_rate": "1h",
        "includes": [ "*.doc" , "*.xls", "*.txt" ]
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "docs1",
        "type": "doc1",
        "bulk_size": 50
    }  
}
```

Inside `d://tmp`  I have a simple txt  file with person name.
But when I am executing the command to check document, I am not getting any document.

```
GET docs1/doc1/_search
output : 
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
 }
```

In elasticsearch console, I have following log:

```
[2015-05-23 12:40:40,645][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Ulysses] [.marvel-2015.05.23] update_mapping [cluster_stats] (dynamic)
[2015-05-23 12:40:54,037][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Ulysses] [_river] creating index, cause [auto(index api)], templates [], shards [1]/[1], mappings [mynewriver2]
[2015-05-23 12:40:56,511][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Ulysses] [_river] update_mapping [mynewriver2] (dynamic)
[2015-05-23 12:40:57,023][INFO ][fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river.fs.river.FsRiver] [Ulysses] [fs][mynewriver2] Starting fs river scanning
[2015-05-23 12:40:57,309][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Ulysses] [docs1] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2015-05-23 12:41:00,762][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Ulysses] [.marvel-2015.05.23] update_mapping [index_event] (dynamic)
```

I am running elasticsearch 1.5.2 in windows 7 ( 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a Windows system, it looks like the specified path is not correct according to [the documentation](https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver#choose-scanned-directory), i.e. you should either use **two back slashes instead of two forward slashes** in your path OR a **single forward slash**. Can you try to delete your river and re-create it like this

```
PUT _river/mynewriver2/_meta
{
    "type": "fs",
    "fs": {
        "url": "d:\\tmp",
        "update_rate": "1h",
        "includes": [ "*.doc" , "*.xls", "*.txt" ]
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "docs1",
        "type": "doc1",
        "bulk_size": 50
    }  
}
```

or like this:

```
PUT _river/mynewriver2/_meta
{
    "type": "fs",
    "fs": {
        "url": "d:/tmp",
        "update_rate": "1h",
        "includes": [ "*.doc" , "*.xls", "*.txt" ]
    },
    "index": {
        "index": "docs1",
        "type": "doc1",
        "bulk_size": 50
    }  
}
```

Comment: I tried with above mentioned approach. Still not working

Comment: Is it working with your windows system? From log I came to know that request is not going to fsriver plugin.